# Как правильно извлекать данные помеченные тегами?

Tags: sqlite, база-данных, sql

Создал базу данных для хранения данных с помощью тегов. При создании руководствовался этими ссылками: [ссылка 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387006/getting-tags-for-content-from-second-table-in-one-sql), [ссылка 2](http://www.askdev.ru/databases/705/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5). И в итоге создал три таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE "content"(
    "id"             Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "content"        Text NOT NULL,
    "content (html)" Text NOT NULL, "additionally" Text,
CONSTRAINT "Unique_1" UNIQUE ( "id" ) )

CREATE TABLE "tag"(
    "id"   Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "name" Text NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "Unique_1" UNIQUE ( "id" ),
CONSTRAINT "Unique_2" UNIQUE ( "name" ) )

CREATE TABLE "content_tag" (
  "id_content" int NOT NULL,
  "id_tag" VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "id_content_tag" UNIQUE ("id_content","id_tag"),
  CONSTRAINT "content_tag_ibfk_1" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("id_content") REFERENCES "content" ("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("id_tag") REFERENCES "tag" ("id")
)
```

Все работает - данные правильно добавляются. Но я не умею извлекаться необходимые мне записи. К примеру в результате добавления некоторых данных таблица `content_tag` приобретает следующий вид:

```
content_tag
============
id_content   id_tag
---------  -------
      1        1
      1        3
      1        7
      2        2
      2        3
      2        7
```

1) Как получить номера записей с
    тегами `1`?
    2) Нужно получить записи, которые
    помеченны тегами `1` и `7` (запись
    должна иметь именно два тега, а не
    только один из них)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так:

```
select id_content 
from content_tag
where 
  id_tag in (1,7)
group by id_content
having count(*)=2
```

(1,7) - ваш список тэгов. 2 - длина вашего списка тэгов.

ЗЫ Легко модифицируется под "хотя бы m тэгов из n тэгов присутствуют"...
ЗЗЫ не проверял

Comment: Отлияно работает для запроса 2! Но все-таки помогите сделать запрос - получить номера записей с тегами 1 и 7 (не обязательно, чтобы присутствовали два тега вместе).

Comment: @derkode, так: 

    id_tag in (1,2,3,4,5) ... having count(*) >= 1 -- хотя бы один тэг из списка
    id_tag in (1,2,3,4,5) ... having count(*) >= 3 -- как минимум три тэга
    id_tag in (1,2,3,4,5) ... having count(*) = 4 -- ровно четыре тэга из списка